# Make request to local server on port 8080

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, server, request

I have now the following flow.

```
example.com => https://example-example.mycompany.com => myproxy => someServer
```

I am right now developing `myproxy` and it changes the answers that the clients of the website `example.com` are receiving.

In order to test this, I thought that the best idea I could come up with was changing my local machine (in which I have an instance of `myproxy` running on the port `8080`) so I redirect only my requests that go to `example-example.mycompany.com` to `localhost:8080`

I have tried with `nginx` adding the following configurationbut I was unable... and also changing `/etc/hosts` didn't help me.

#### Question

**Is there any way to change the call of `example-example.mycompany.com` *JUST* for my computer, so that while I am testing there is no client of `example.com` affected by the changes in the local `myproxy`?**

#### Trials

- Create a docker container running in 8080 and 80 and try to make the requests against it

`docker run --name my-custom-nginx-container -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -p 80:80 -p 3000:8080 --rm -d nginx`

- Creating an nginx server (so I don't have issues with containers maybe not being properly bind)

nginx.conf

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name example-example.mycompany.com;

            location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3000/ https://$server_name/;
            }
    }
```

- Adding the example-example.mycompany.com to the etc/hosts file (didn't do anything)

`/etc/hosts`

`127.0.0.1    example-example.mycompany.com`

**NOTE:** I've seen it work in the computer of my coworker which is using windows. I can't get it to work in Linux/MacOs.